# Schema Structured Markup

Tags: html, schema, structured-data

I'm trying to apply some structured markup to a TheatreEvent. Heres the code I'm working with:

```
 <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->

  <div class="container" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/TheaterEvent">   

    <div class="col-md-3">

      <div class="event-details">
        <h3>Event Info</h3>
        <p itemprop="startDate"><strong>Date: </strong><?php the_field('date_of_event'); ?></p>
        <p itemprop="doorTime"><strong>Time: </strong><?php the_field('start_time'); ?> – <?php the_field('end_time'); ?></p>
        <p><strong>Price: </strong><?php the_field('price'); ?></p>
        <p><strong>Venue: </strong><?php the_field('venue'); ?></p>
      </div>
      <div class="book-event-button">
        <a href="<?php the_field('button_link'); ?>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-plum btn-lg btn-event" role="button"><?php the_field('button_text');?></a>
      </div> 
      <div class="book-event-button" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <a href="<?php the_field('event_pack_upload'); ?>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-teal btn-lg btn-event" role="button"><?php the_field('event_pack_button_text');?></a>
      </div> 
      <div class="book-event-button" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/youth-community/support-us/events/tips-tools/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-plum btn-lg btn-event" role="button">TIPS AND TOOLS</a>
      </div> 
    </div>    



    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1 itemprop="name"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p itemprop="description"><?php the_field('event_description'); ?></p>
      </div>      
    </div>      

  </div>
```

You can see I have tried to add the markup using itemtype and itemprop etc... but I'm seeing lots of errors in the google checker: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

The page is here: https://www.leicesterymca.co.uk/show/?showid=b74e95df-58f7-e611-80d7-00505601004c and I did wonder is the info spreading over two DIVs was a problem...

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that you have to modify in your site to fulfill the Schema Guideline.

I tried to give you the demo from your site with the proper data.

```
<div class="container" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/TheaterEvent">   

 <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="event-details">
        <h3>Event Info</h3>
        <strong>Date: </strong><p itemprop="startDate">Sun 21 May 2017 19:30</p>
        <strong>Time: </strong><p itemprop="duration">20:00</p>
    </div>
 </div>    

 <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="page-header">
       <h1 itemprop="name">The Wild Swan World Tour</h1>
       <div itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PerformingArtsTheater">
          <meta itemprop="name" content="Shakespeare's Globe"/>
          <meta itemprop="address" content="London, UK"/>
       </div>
       <p itemprop="description">Foy Vance knows how to write a song. It’s a naturally-born but dedicatedly-finessed skill that has led him to collaborate with artists as diverse as Plan B, Sheryl Crow and Rudimental, synced his music on multiple TV shows ranging from Grey’s Anatomy to the finale of Sons Of Anarchy, and caught the ears of some of the biggest players (in every sense) in music, from Elton John to Ed Sheeran.</p>
   </div>      
 </div>     

 <div itemprop="workPerformed" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
    <div itemprop="creator" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="William Shakespeare"/>
    </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Please note that Name and Location properties must require when you are trying to display Schema with [TheaterEvent](http://schema.org/TheaterEvent).

The format for Date and Time should be [ISO 8601 date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Still, there will be 4 Warnings when you test the above code in Schema Testing Tool but that you can avoid if there isn't any such data.

You can check more with demo in above TheaterEvent link.